# Display array records in dynamically added rows in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, dynamic, row

Upon creating a record I am using a dynamic row to add product items. Just to give you an idea here's the code I adopt to my purchase order app.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $("#quantity-" + i).change(function() {
    upd_art(i)
  });
  $("#price-" + i).change(function() {
    upd_art(i)
  });


  $('#add').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#articles').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="number" value=0 id="quantity-' + i + '" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity" class="form-control name_list" /></td> <td><input type="number" id="price-' + i + '" name="price[]" value=0  placeholder="price" class="form-control name_list" /></td> <td><input type="number" id="total-' + i + '" name="total[]" placeholder="total" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td> <td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

    $("#quantity-" + i).change(function() {
      upd_art(i)
    });
    $("#price-" + i).change(function() {
      upd_art(i)
    });


  });


  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

  $('#submit').click(function() {
    alert($('#add_name').serialize()); //alerts all values           
    $.ajax({
      url: "wwwdb.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#add_name').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#add_name')[0].reset();
      }
    });
  });

  function upd_art(i) {
    var qty = $('#quantity-' + i).val();
    var price = $('#price-' + i).val();
    var totNumber = (qty * price);
    var tot = totNumber.toFixed(2);
    $('#total-' + i).val(tot);
  }



  //  setInterval(upd_art, 1000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
      <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="articles">
            <tr class="rrjeshta">

              <td><input value=0 type="number" id="quantity-0" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantity" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
              <td><input value=0 type="number" id="price-0" name="price[]" placeholder="price" class="form-control name_list" /></td>

              <td><input type="number" id="total-0" name="total[]" placeholder="total" class="form-control name_list" readonly /></td>
              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add new</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In my project, it has the product name, product code, price, and quantity. I have no issues on saving the record.

My problem is, how will I be able to display the records from that form with dynamic row function?

I am dealing with 2 tables, the **ORDERS** (transaction details are being saved here like the purchase order number grand total, currency etc) and **ORDER_ITEMS** (the items produced from that dynamic row are being saved here).

I believe I set up the eloquent relation properly but the areas that puzzled me are the part where I need to display the order items in the dynamic row, and then the ability to add another row should still be there.

Any suggestions? or probably a reference link that might help solve this problem? If you still want anything from my code please let me know.

Thank you very much guys in advance!

## UPDATE

I have an idea to but I don't know how to translate into a code since I am not a coder.

here's my idea, I will count the number of an items inside the array using jQuery, let say it has 5 items in that array, and then I will append that number to the dynamic rows so there will be 5 rows, then the 5 items will be  place there. since the process is jQuery, the ability to add new row will still be available. I think these are easier said than done. Please if you could guide me to a reference links that can solve my problem please let me know. or if you can provide me some codes that I can start with.

again guys thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Is your idea to not fetch, nor dispatch latest data from the server after POST, and only count data in the frontend?

Comment: hi @Bart sorry I did not get your question.

Comment: any suggestion guys? :(

Answer (score 0):

For the answer, follow this link. [Calculating the columns inside foreach using jQuery is not working in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984563/calculating-the-columns-inside-foreach-using-jquery-is-not-working-in-laravel/54984739?noredirect=1#comment96731252_54984739) its not the actual but the whole logic is there. good luck to those who faced same problem as mine. :)