# Calculating the columns inside foreach using jQuery is not working in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a table that is being populated by the items from database. I use **foreach** to dynamically add rows for the next items. And also I use **jquery** to calculate the price and quantity per row but the problem is I can't make it work. here's my Code,

```
@php
    $counter = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($order->orderItems as $orderItem)
@php
    $counter++; 
@endphp
    <tr>
        <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type='text' data-type="product_code" id='product_code_{{$counter}}' name='product_code[]' for="1" value="{{ $orderItem->product_code }}" required/></td>
        <td><input class="form-control autocomplete_txt" type='text' data-type="product_name" id='product_name_{{$counter}}' name='product_name[]' for="1" value="{{ $orderItem->product_name }}" required/></td>
        <td><input class="form-control product_price" type='number' data-type="product_price" id='product_price_{{$counter}}' name='cost[]' for="1" value="{{ $orderItem->cost }}" required/></td>
        <td><input class="form-control quantity" type='number' id='quantity_{{$counter}}' name='quantity[]' for="1" value="{{ $orderItem->quantity }}" required/></td>
        <td><input class="form-control total_cost" type='text' id='total_cost_1' name='total_cost[]' for='1' value="{{ $orderItem->total_cost }}" readonly/>
            <input class="form-control product_id" type='hidden' data-type="product_id" id='product_id_{{ $orderItem->id }}' name='product_id[]'/>
            <input class="form-control product_id" type='hidden' data-type="order_id" id='oder_id_{{ $orderItem->id }}' name='order_id[]' value="1" /></td>
        <td>
            @if ($counter % 1 == 0 && $counter > 1)
            @else
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success circle"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
            @endif
        </td>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var calc = {{$counter}};

            function getTotalCost(calc) {
                var qty1 = $('#quantity_'+calc).val();
                var price1 = $('#product_price_'+calc).val();
                var totNumber1 = (qty1 * price1);
                var tot1 = totNumber1.toLocaleString("en-US", { maximumFractionDigits: 2});
                $('#total_cost_'+calc).val(tot1);
                calculateSubTotal1();
            }
            function calculateSubTotal1() {
                var grandtotal1 = 0;
                $('.total_cost').each(function() {
                    grandtotal1 += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g,''));
                });                    
                $('#grandtotal').val(grandtotal1.toLocaleString("en-US", { maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
            }
        </script>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Please help. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting your DOM to load entirely. Inside your loop:

```html
@foreach (...)
...
<script>
// Execute your DOM manipulations when document is ready.
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calc = {{$counter}};

    getTotalCost(calc);
});
</script>
...
@endforeach
```

Outside:

```html
<script>
    function getTotalCost(calc) {
        var qty1 = $('#quantity_'+calc).val();
        var price1 = $('#product_price_'+calc).val();
        var totNumber1 = (qty1 * price1);
        var tot1 = totNumber1.toLocaleString("en-US", { maximumFractionDigits: 2});

        $('#total_cost_'+calc).val(tot1);

        calculateSubTotal1();
    }

    function calculateSubTotal1() {
        var grandtotal1 = 0;

        $('.total_cost').each(function() {
            grandtotal1 += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g,''));
        });    

        $('#grandtotal').val(grandtotal1.toLocaleString("en-US", { maximumFractionDigits: 2}));
    }
</script>
```

---

**TIPS:**

In a `foreach` loop in blade, you have access to a generated variable called `$loop`.

And with what I can see, your `$counter` variable has the same result as a property of the `$loop` one: `$loop->iteration`.

Check the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops) for more properties of a blade loop.

Comment: Hi @iArcadia its still not working. I moved the script out of foreach.

Comment: @LitoLozada You can't move your script because your PHP variable `$counter` will not be defined, and so will throw an error. The anonymous function passed as a argument to `ready()` will be executed when your DOM is loaded, even if your `<script>` tag is placed in your loop.

Comment: Also added a tip for blade loop in my answer.

Comment: Hi @iArcadia I just return the script to its previous location. It is still not working. Also thank you for the documentation link.

Comment: Your `getTotalCost` function is defined but never executed. You should move your two defined functions outside your loop in another `<script>` tag. Then, execute `getTotalCost` in each iteration of the loop. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Well, in your javascript, you used the selector `'#total_cost_' + calc`, but in your HTML, the input you want to target has the ID `total_cost_1` for each loop iteration. Maybe you should also convert into number your variables `qty1` and `price1` when you get input values.

Comment: Hi @iArcadia awesome catch hhaha I add loop iteration in #total_cost. Together with your suggestions, I add this at the top of function getTotalCost1(calc), this one,                 $("#orders").on('input', 'input.quantity,input.product_price', function() {
                  getTotalCost($(this).attr("for"));
                });  and apply iterations in FOR="" in all my inputs, for="{{$loop->iteration}}" . it is working now

Comment: I am glad to hear that! Hope you will remember that if you encouter that problem again! :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, javascript would not be able to recognize the $counter variable you are passing to it in your script tag from PHP. try wrapping your double mustasche with quotes like so let count = "{{$counter}}" or using let count = {!! $count !!}. Try this and see if your logic works.

Comment: I don't see why, `$counter` is an integer